# How to get get pups or divide this overgrown aloe vera plant?

Tags: succulents, cactus, transplanting, aloe

I have a very large aloe vera plant. I cannot see any pups/babies. Is there a way I can divide it into more pots, either so the original isn't as big or just just to have more aloe vera plants?
It's hard to tell from picture but it's very big. I'm having trouble finding pots big enough for it.
[image: photo of plant]

Would cutting off a leaf and putting it in another pot work?